# Password Protect ALL Excel Macro Creation and Use

Tags: vba, security, excel

I have a spreadsheet that I have password protected from allowing users to edit.

I would also like to password protect ANY and ALL actions related to Macros within this spreadsheet. I don't want anyone to be able to create a new macro in this sheet, run an old macro in this sheet, or even run a macro stored in another place on the computer.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible unless you have access to the end-user's macro security settings and can turn off macros in Excel all together.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in excel. There may be some system adminy thing you can do with Group Policies to force macro security, but that would affect all excel spreadsheets for that user, and not just the specific one you want. The whole idea is Excel is a document, not an application. Documents by design are reproduced and shared, and what the end user does with it is his/her perogative.